# How to pass pandas df value as hmtl tag id with Flask

Tags: html, flask, html-rendering

Hello there I am rendering a table in html using flask, so how can i pass ticket id from my df as hmtl tag id

df :

|  | ticket | cost | comission | pnl | result | Total Accumulated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 123 | 123 | 123 | 123 | 123 | 123 |
| 1 | 321 | 321 | 321 | 321 | 321 | 321 |

my current code :

```
            <td id="ticket">
              {{row['ticket']}}
            </td>
```

But what is need is something like :

```
            <td id={{row['ticket']}}>
              {{row['ticket']}}
            </td>
```